# Html CSS Scrolling Background Full screen

Tags: html, css, background, sliding

I need help on this project for this website...

Si I have most everything down. But I need my scrolling background to vertically stretch across the entire screen not just the top.

Here is the website hosted on an external server until I get this problem fixed so i can migrate it to my real server...

http://jacksonmilburn.bitballoon.com

The problem is that if you zoom all he way out you can see white on the bottom.

Here is my CSS Code:

```
.sliding-background {
background: url("images/bg.jpg") repeat-x;
height: 1080px;
width: 27162px;
animation: slide 60s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slide{
0%{
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
100%{
transform: translate3d(-9054px, 0, 0);
```

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<div  

class="sliding-background"
 ></div>
```

Comment: I think the problem are the measurements in pixel (fixed), if you find a way to make percentage measures work, zoom should not be a problem anymore.

Comment: Am I the only one who STILL thinks keyframes are confusing and out preformed by JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using width and height as pixels
change them into:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

That will make the image big and make it responsive to your browser window size
also try this code to make your image a full background:

```
.sliding-background {
  background: url("images/bg.jpg") repeat-x;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Sora mentioned your div should fill its parent's height.

Use this style:

```
.sliding-background {
    position: absolute; /*Usually height: 100% does not work if your div is not absolute or fixed.*/
    height: 100% !important; /*Stretch the height of the element*/
    width: 10000%; /* Really lengthy width */

    /*Your style*/

    /*background-size: cover;*/ /*Just stretching the element's height is not sufficient - So you have to tell the browser to scale the background of the div to cover the all visible area (by stretching proportionately)*/
    background-size: contain; /* This tries to fit the image in the div area - since the div's width is too great. It always fills vertically. */
}
```

And I would suggest you to replace the width with percentage too.

**UPDATE:**

And this method is preferably better,

```
.sliding-background {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    /*Your style*/

    background-size: auto 100%; /* Make sure you call background-size after the background. */
}
```

And animate `background-position-x` instead of `transform:translate(x, y);`

i.e.,

```
@keyframes slide{
    0%{
        background-position-x: 0px;
    }
    100%{
        background-position-x: -9054px; /* or something */
    }
}
```

**Note:** You see, in the first implementation, the page is horizontally scrollable. I suggest you to opt the second implementation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey. This worked really well. thanks. But I also want it to always be centered. Like when we have a smaller screen it only shows the top... How can I get it to be centered?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand you. You mean vertically center? Do you see white space at bottom? Or you are viewing only the top area of the background image?

Comment: Oh! I think I understand your issue now. I have updated the answer, that should work for your requirement. Let me know if this is not what you asked for.

Comment: That Worked Perfectly thanks so much. Now with the background-position-x the webpage doesn't scroll... Do you know a fix for that. I updated the website if you want to see.

Comment: I am glad it worked as you expected. Please accept the answer. Do you want the page to horizontally scroll or vertically scroll?

Comment: I want it to scroll like it used to automatically horizontal... It stopped moving at all.

Comment: Oh! I tested it and it works. Use the `slide` keyframe animation, I provided and make sure you call it on `.sliding-background` too - Which I didn't do! And if you still didn't get it to scroll, post this in a jsfiddle and I will check.

Comment: Can you post your code in jsfiddle.com, there I can modify the code and save it and then you can take it from there and implement in your project.

Comment: There are way to many files to put it jsfiddle. I have 3 css files.... but this is what i could do.